# Is a knot $K$ and it's mirror image $^*K$ considered the same knot in terms of tabulating prime knots? If so, why?

Tags: knot-theory

I'm just wanting to confirm whether this is the case and why? Is it purely to do with the sheer number of knot projections that would have to be dealt with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A knot and its mirror image are not always the same, but when it comes to knot tables, most people do not bother drawing both.  I believe this is just for space and the fact that we can pretty much visualize what the mirror image looks like. But there is a way to tell.

Most tables will then provide the Jones Polynomial of the knot, which can distinguish mirror images.  It is usually given by some sequence of numbers like: $\{-4\}(-1, 1, 0, 1)$ which means a polynomial with $-4$ exponent as the leading term and $-1$ as its coefficient. So, the actual polynomial is $-t^{-4}+t^{-3}+t^{-1}$, which is the trefoil. The impressive fact that if you substitute $t^{-1}$ in for $t$, it will be the polynomial of the mirror image, is why the Jones polynomial is so powerful. If the two polynomials you get this way are *not* equal, the mirror images are *not* equivalent. Notice, they are not equivalent for the trefoil.

But for the figure eight knot, $\{-2\}(1,-1,1,-1,1)$ is symmetric, so by the Jones polynomial, it *may* be equivalent to its mirror image, as pointed out by Grumpy Parsnip, and in this case, it is.

Comment: Something you said is not correct. If the Jones polynomial is not symmetric, you can conclude the knot is not equivalent to its mirror image, but the converse is false. Take a connected sum of a knot and the mirror image of a mutation of that knot. It had symmetric Jones polynomial, but will not be amphicheiral in general.

Comment: You are correct, but we were only speaking about knot tables, where connected sums are not included.  So, for all prime knots, what I said is correct.

Comment: There's no reason to expect the Jones Polynomial to be a complete invariant of amphicheirality, even in the case of prime knots.

Comment: Ah, I see your point.  Is there a known example of a prime that has symmetric with nonequivalent mirror image, or is that open?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would try mutating an amphicheiral knot. That will leave its Jones polynomial unchanged but probably destroy the symmetry.